# How to get the Index id in Angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to get the html generated id value in typescript ngOnInit().
This is the question for Angular2
Here is the scenario.

```
<html>
<div *ngFor='let post of data; let i = index' [attr.data-index]="i">

<button id="cdata_{{i}}">Click<button>

//here id will generate for the button in loop

</div>
</html>
```

Now in typescript (.ts) file

```
ngOnInit(){
    //How to get the index value here in this function?Without any click function in html.
}
```

I have to write that onInit.this should load on the page load. The id which i generated,is showing on the Html page but,i want the get those id to perform some operation in `typescript>ngOnInit`.

in `ngOnInit(){}`,this should be something like this=> 
    `this.service.x.subscribe(data=>{ 
var indexK=document.getElementById("cdata_"+i); 
console.log("indexK"); })`

This one is not working.This should be print like

```
cdata_0 
cdata_1 
cdata_2 
cdata_3
```

Comment: My scenario is that buddy. @vicbyte

Comment: Within the same component it makes no sense for me. Each value has an index value, which one do you want. 
I think what you want to achieve is to get the index of button clicked (that's a scenario)

If so, add a (click)="buttonClicked($event, index)" in your button, then create a buttonClicked function and get the index id.

Comment: It's not the scenario. I have to write that onInit.this should load on the page load. The id which i generated,is showing on the Html page but,i want the get those id to perform some operation in typescript>ngOnInit.

Comment: in ngOnInit(){},this should be something like this=>
this.service.x.subscribe(data=>{
var indexK=document.getElementById("cdata_"+i);
console.log("indexK");
})

This one is not working.This should be print like cdata_0 cdata_1 cdata_2 cdata_3

Comment: Why must you write it in this specific way? Wouldn't you prefer to write it a better (proper) way? Why not tell us what you want to achieve rather than how you want to achieve it? That might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reach the DOM you cannot get elements by id from ngOnInit because there is no DOM loaded yet. You need to call your function like this (or you can use observable)

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
 data.forEach((item, index) => {
    var indexK=document.getElementById("cdata_"+index); 
    console.log("indexK");
  });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But i have to do that with calling any function. I was done that in another way. I was directly wrote the conditions on the html page. No need to write a function or call.